# How to make this code more dynamic and functional?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a jQuery function that adds a class "active" to aside block when scrolling to the related block in another block.
The code is working, but I want to make it more dynamic and functional.

```
if ($('.reglementation .nav.nav-pills').length > 0) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    var screenPosition = $(document).scrollTop() + 20;

    if (screenPosition >= $('#tab272').offset().top) {
      $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.nav li a[href="#tab272"]').addClass('active');
    }

    if (screenPosition >= $('#tab275').offset().top) {
      $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.nav li a[href="#tab275"]').addClass('active');
    }

    if (screenPosition >= $('#tab278').offset().top) {
      $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.nav li a[href="#tab278"]').addClass('active');
    }

    if (screenPosition >= $('#tab285').offset().top) {
      $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.nav li a[href="#tab285"]').addClass('active');
    }

    if (screenPosition >= $('#tab290').offset().top) {
      $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.nav li a[href="#tab290"]').addClass('active');
    }

    if (screenPosition >= $('#tab300').offset().top) {
      $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.nav li a[href="#tab300"]').addClass('active');
    }
    if (screenPosition >= $('#tab377').offset().top) {
      $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('ul.nav li a[href="#tab377"]').addClass('active');
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: What issues are you facing while trying to make it more dynamic and functional?

Comment: i want to wrap it in a loop so i don't have to add a condition each time, the issue is i'm using an ID that it's generated automatically and i'm confused about how i suppose to know every paragraphe ID and it's relative anchor

Comment: check my code, you can select all the tags which has ID starting with a word, this is possible , and you can dynamically read the ID of any tag

Comment: Why not use a class instead of basing it on a partial match of id?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var screenPosition = $(document).scrollTop() + 20;
    var currentTab = null;

    $(document).find('*[id^="tab"]').each(function(){
        if ( screenPosition >= $(this).offset().top ){
            currentTab = $(this);
        }
    });

    $('ul.nav').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.nav').find('a[href="#' + currentTab.attr('id') + '"]').addClass('active');
}
```

You can find currentTab by comparing offset of each tabs with screenPosition.
And then remove active class from current, and addClass to new element.

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of putting `ID` for each tab simply a single CSS class for all tag
2. Write a code which will identify the position for all tabs in one loop and for whichever satisfies the condition make it active

this technique will make the code less than 6 lines

Example

```
  var screenPosition = $(document).scrollTop() + 20;
  $.each($('[id^="tab"]'), function(index, value) {
       if (screenPosition >= $(value).offset().top) {
         $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
         $('ul.nav li a[href="#' + $(value).attr("id") + '"]').addClass('active');
       }
  });
```

I think this 6 line code is enough

Comment: Your code will add 'active' class to all of tabs that have small position than current screenPosition, please refer my answer.

Comment: may be, but `$('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active')` this code itself is a global select, inside if or outside if doesn't matter

Comment: Have you ever test your code? There will be multiple active elements at the same time. Because you remove classes first and then add class to matched elements.

Comment: there is an if condition inside the loop, only those will be activated, all others will be inactive, putting the first line inside if and outside if make no difference, reason being it is a global select with no specific local element

Comment: If screenPosition is large than offset of Tab1 and Tab2, then links for these both of 2 tabs will have active class.

Comment: but the person who asked question himself is doing the same, he did not mension only one element he wanted to highlight

Comment: It is not same, because he remove class within if statement, though previous tab had active class, it will removed, but you removing class before than each and if statement, your code will select multiple elements to active.

Comment: my code will select all the previous active elements and make it inactive first, that is actual description, I tested it

Answer (score 0):

hope that will help check it out # happy coding

```
var screenPosition = $(document).scrollTop() + 20;
var tabs = ['#tab275', '#tab278']; // list your tabs

//add and remove the classes in function

function removeAddClass(tab) {
if (screenPosition >= $(tab).offset().top) {
    $('ul.nav li').parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.nav li a[href="' + tab + '"]').addClass('active');
  }
}
if ($('.reglementation .nav.nav-pills').length > 0) {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // loop over the tabs 
    //and set each tab to be handeld by 
    //the removeAddClass functio
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
        removeAddClass(tab);
        console.log(tab);
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code finds the index `i` of the first tab that is *further* than the screen position and selects the tab *preceding* it.

If there is no tab further than the screen position, the last tab index is used.

```js
const articles = ['#one', '#two', '#three']

function onScroll() {
  const screenPos = window.pageYOffset + 20
  const i = articles.findIndex((el) => $(el).offset().top > screenPos)
  const j = (i === -1) ? articles.length-1 : i-1
  const previous = $('nav a.active')
  const current = $(`nav a[href="${articles[j]}"]`)
  if(current[0] === previous[0]) return
  $('nav').find('a.active').removeClass('active')
  $(`nav a[href="${articles[j]}"]`).addClass('active')
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
onScroll()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 135px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 350px;
  z-index: 1;
}
article {
  width: 330px;
  height: 600px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px silver inset;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
nav a.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,200,200,1);
}
nav a {
  color: black;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px silver inset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .5s ease-out 0s
}
main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
<a href="#three">Three</a>
</nav>
<main>
<article id="one">Article 1</article>
<article id="two">Article 2</article>
<article id="three">Article 3</article>
</main>
```